# Copy data to another sheet with if else logic statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data into columns on another worksheet based on a logical statement.

This statement checks if the value in a column on Sheet1 is equal to "Implementation" or "Validation".

- If the value in a cell in that column is "Implementation"

  - paste values from column E on Sheet1 into column C on Sheet2.
- If the value is "Validation"

  - paste values from column E on Sheet1 into column E on Sheet2.

My code executes with no errors but doesn't do anything. Googling has me more confused.

Here is my whole code, relevant code underneath it:

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ReadSheet As Worksheet
Dim WriteSheet As Worksheet

Dim TaskType As Range
Dim AssignedTo As Range
Dim ImplemAssign As Range
Dim ValidAssign As Range

'Creating variables for Worksheets for ease of use
Set ReadSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WriteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Task Type variable for ease of use
Set TaskType = ReadSheet.Range("D2:D1000")

'Implementation and Assignment Employee Names
Set AssignedTo = ReadSheet.Range("E2:E1000")
Set ImplemAssign = WriteSheet.Range("C2:C1000")
Set ValidAssign = WriteSheet.Range("E2:E1000")

'Clear existing data before re-writing to sheet
WriteSheet.Range("A2:E1000").Clear

'Decide if to copy based on Task Type
If TaskType.Text = "Implementation" Then
    AssignedTo.Copy
    ImplemAssign.PasteSpecial

ElseIf TaskType.Text = "Validation" Then
    AssignedTo.Copy
    ValidAssign.PasteSpecial

End If
End Sub
```

Relevant Code:

```
'Decide if to copy based on Task Type
If TaskType.Text = "Implementation" Then
    AssignedTo.Copy
     ImplemAssign.PasteSpecial

ElseIf TaskType.Text = "Validation" Then
    AssignedTo.Copy
    ValidAssign.PasteSpecial

End If
```

Comment: You need a loop. Or a filter.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'll figure out how to do that and see what happens!

Comment: Tried a loop, still nothing happened.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the loop?